# Can I have a common .env file for my app and its dependency?

Tags: javascript, webpack, environment-variables

I did something like this:

```
root/
  node_modules/
    myPackage/
      index.js // uses the .env, can access process.env

  app.js // uses the .env, can access process.env
   .env
```

In app.js, the process object is a global, when I import myPackage the global object is also available in myPackeg/index.js. All good, hurray.

But, the node_modules/myPackage is not bundled, its just a couple of .js files with entry point at index.js. If myPackege is run through webpack build (minified, mangled) it somehow no longer is able to inherit the global process object from app.js. I don't understand why.

Webpack config of myPackage is nothing special, compiles to ES5, UMD. The code was mangled though, I excluded the 'process' from being mangled but it didn't help.

What am I missing?

webpack.config.js (without transplanting to ES5 with Babel)

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './lib/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'myModule',
    library: 'myModule',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      lodash: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/lodash'),
      'bn.js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bn.js'),
    },
  },
  node: {
    Buffer: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: do you define the variable in your webpack config (using DefinePlugin)?  
Could you share it would be easier to know what's going on

Comment: @h1b9b Is DefinePlugin required for what I want to do? Added webpack config to the quesiton.

Comment: yes, cause it's used to define env variables for the app process as the webpack process isn't the app process